# Android App Delivery

Tags: android

I am new to Android, working through some tutorials - but I cannot find anything that mentions the delivery mechanism.

Once I complete an app - how do I launch it, there must be tonnes of documentation but I cant find it. Not sure what to Google for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To publish your app on the market you will need an Android Developper Account and signing your app.

Everything needed is here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a good documentation on the official [google docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing_overview.html)

Answer (score 2):

As for publishing the app on Google's market, [see here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html)

As for debugging the app on your phone, [see here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Also, I recommend using Eclipse with the [ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) to develop, deploy and test your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good answer too: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/

It's not better than official google one but I think it's usefull!